# Calling Get Request with Json Body using httpclient

Tags: c#, xamarin, .net-core, xamarin.forms, httpclient

I came with an issue this morning where the Api which I am calling is a Get Method but to get Get the Data from it I had to send the json body this is working good when I am testing it in the post man but I am not able to implement it in my project where I am calling this using HttpClient

here is the screenshot of post

[image]

It also have a bearer token which I pass in Authorization

Now when I am try to implement this at client side here is my code

```
  var stringPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri("https://myapiendpoint/serviceability/"),
            Content = new StringContent(stringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
        };
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

when I call this method using this code I get

```
System.Net.HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed - Status code 405
```

I also tried changing this line

```
 Method = HttpMethod.Get to Method = HttpMethod.Post
```

but still getting same error

I know this is bad implementation at API Side the request ideally should be POST but changing this is not in my hand and hence need to find the solution

Comment: oof, you might be able to do it using tcp instead. You could also try a WebClient.

Comment: @John I am trying to implement this in my Xamarin Project

Comment: WebClient works for me in my Xamarin project. You can also try WebClient.UploadData. Also are you sure application/json is the right format? It could just be text and not json and thats why the server rejects you.

Comment: HttpClient is not designed to work for GET requests with a body.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

almost search all over and trying all the variant of using GET Method finally the solution which worked for me in this case was this

```
var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://baseApi/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", token));
            var query = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                ["pickup_postcode"] = 400703,
                ["delivery_postcode"] = 421204,
                ["cod"] = "0",
                ["weight"] = 2,
            };

            var url = "methodurl";
            var response = await client.GetAsync(QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(url, query));
            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(responseBody);
```

Got QueryHelpers from Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities package

Comment: You can mark this answer which will help more people with same problem:).